# Return a char * in c and send it as a parameter to another function

Tags: c, char

I would like to know how can I return a string in c and then send it as a parameter to another funcion. For example, in those functions:

This is the function that returns a `char *`:

```
char * read(){
    char c[4];
    printf("Write the string:\n");
    scanf(" %[^\n]", c);
    return c;
}
```

And this one takes it as a parameter and prints it:

```
void printc(char *a){
    printf("%s", a);
}
```

I've tried doing:

```
printc(read());
```

But it doesn't work. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: @kalia  "The best way" is to declare the array outside the functions and pass it as an argument to the both functions.:)

Comment: 1. *"Doesn't work"* is not a proper problem description - be as precise as you can be. 2. Your `read` function is returning a pointer to a local array, whose lifetime ends after the function ends

Comment: `char c[4];` --> `static char c[4];`

Comment: @VladfromMoscow But I would like to know if there's any way in c to pass a string between two functions

Comment: @kalia And I wrote how to do this.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow okay, thank you.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY yea, lets go `static` and wait for the awkward moment when someone decides to use `read` for some purpose inside the `printc` implementation.